# what are the differences between __strong and strong, __weak and weak?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am a noob in ios programming. Please, explain me the meaning for these **__strong and __weak** properties and why they are used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`strong` and `weak` are modifiers used in property declarations while `__strong` and `__weak` are used in declarations of variables.